# How to persist kdb tables to compressed parquet?

Tags: parquet, kdb, pyarrow, fastparquet

I'm trying to store/persist kdb tables in compressed [apache parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) format.
My initial plan is basically to use [embedPy](https://github.com/KxSystems/embedPy) to convert either [fastparquet](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [pyarrow.parquet](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html) to be usable from within q.
I'll then use the kdb+ tick architecture to process incoming ticks and run daily batched parquet writes to disk.
Would this be a good idea? Otherwise what would be the best method of persisting large amounts of data to disk? thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use pyq rather than embedPy? With pyq your process can behave like a standard kdb process and have access to python packages without conversion

Comment: Also as a general question - do you need to persist the data to disk in a non-kdb format? Are you trying to make it readable from other applications?

Comment: Hey @terrylynch thanks for the comments, hadn't seen pyq until now will have a look at it. On your second point yes, I would like to make the data available in parquet format for machine learning in Julia and python. Just out of interest, what in your opinion is the best storage persistence method in KDB?

Comment: The best storage persistence method in KDB is KDB's own historical on-disk format. Personally I would write the data in KDB format and serve it up to other applications via an interface/API to KDB. In your case you could write the data in KDB format and have it immediately available to python without conversion (via pyq). If you must have it in a non-KDB format then KDB has built-in writers parsers for csv, json etc. I haven't personally tried any other formats such as parquet